# How can i get button title on another view controller performing segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

1) I am having an 2 view controller on 1st view controller having buttons as
   a) Local  and b) International
 And I am using segment control on another view in which it has 2 bar Local and International 
Now when i perform the segue i need to get the titles or some data so i can identify that which bar should be displayed first the local one or international.

And simply performing the segue doesn't gets the data passed on button event.
So how can i pass 2 different data on two different buttons by performing the segue ?

Answer (score 1):

If the segue is connected to your button, then it will be the sender in prepareForSegue.so write this in prepareForSegue.

```
    NextViewController *vc =        segue.destinationViewController;
    UIButton *dayButton = (UIButton*)sender
    vc.titlestr = sender.titleLabel.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to you view controllers inside prepareForSegue as follow example:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"mysegueidentifier"]){

        NSDictionary *info = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"comment", @"type",
                              @"myId", @"elementId",
                              nil];

        NextViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;

        [vc setSegueInfo:info];
    } 
}
```

NextViewController must have a variable called segueInfo **([vc setSegueInfo:info];)**

@property NSDictionary *segueInfo;

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply i got the solution and implemented my own idea after referring your code.Sorry for not being voted up for your answer as i am newbie to stack overflow and not having enough reputation whenever i would be able i will vote it up.

Comment: Don't worry ;) I'm happy with having helped you!